# How is the PureTalk mobile carrier service in USA to use data mainly

Tags: usa, internet, mobile-operators

I'm travelling to the USA for a few weeks and I need a SIM which I can use mainly for DATA. I have done a small research and find out that "PureTalk" is the cheapest among all as of today. Is there anyone who is using this mobile carrier? How's there coverage and connectivity in USA? I haven't see much reviews on this service provider.

Would like to know if anyone using this carrier in the USA?

Comment: Hi Mad. We don't do price shopping questions, mainly because whatever answer we give would be out of date in a month's time. Sorry.

Comment: While your question is probably off-topic here, a small hint: Research on which bands your mobile phone supports and what the US mobile provider uses. I heard, for example, that T-Mobile USA is not very compatible with german mobile phones, because they don't use many of the same bands.

Comment: I have change the topic of the question. I wanted to know about this "PureTalk" service provider. Whether they are reliable and good in their service.